# iOS device not available in Flutter Device Selection list since iOS16 (Android Studio)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, ios16

My iPhone does not appear in the Flutter Device Selection list in Android Studio anymore. I recently updated to iOS 16. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** Turn on **"Developer Mode"**

Settings > Developer > enable "Developer Mode"

Turns out iOS 16 introduced "Developer Mode", which is turned off by default.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/enabling-developer-mode-on-a-device

Answer (score 0):

On 16.3 it's Settings > Privacy & Security > Developer Mode